# Accessing the onchange event equivalent using javascript dom and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some code in html,

The code is all about calling a function in the onChange event of a select box.

```
<select id="locationLevelId" onChange="abc();">
```

Now,I need the equivalent code using javascript dom and also using jquery ie calling the function abc() for the onChange event.

Comment: What did you try looking for? Entering your exact question title into Google gives out some pretty good results.

Comment: "I need.." is not a good way to describe your problem. Tell us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('locationLevelId').onchange = abc;
```

JQuery

```
$('#locationLevelId').on('change',abc);
```

Comment: Is this the exactcode for the above one, document.getElementById('locationLevelId').onchange= function()
{
    abc();
}

Comment: @seedi yes, should work

Comment: using jquery the exact code is the following,$( "#locationLevelId" ).change(function() {
  abc();
});  am i right?

Comment: yes that will work too but I suggest you follow my updated code to call function `abc`

Comment: ,I have one more doubt is,happening that onchange event dynamically using js don and jquery

Comment: where is that updated code.

Comment: i mean my updated answer. The jquery `.on` event will attach `change` event to dynamically added DOM elements. Refer http://api.jquery.com/on/